# Conflicts within function calls to variables in R

Tags: r, dplyr, phyloseq

I'm somewhat confused with the different values a variable can take within a function and how it is possible to harmonize them so that they suit the different tasks and function calls within the custom function. Here I wrote an example where the argument of the function should be a string for some steps (conditional testing and first function call), and for others it should not (within `dplyr` functions for instance).

```r
# Packages
library(tidyverse)
library(phyloseq)

# Create some data
otu <- data.frame(Sample1 = seq(1,6,1),
                  Sample2 = rep(3.5, 6),
                  Sample3 = c(0,15,0,4,2,0),
                  Sample4 = c(7,7,0,7,0,0))
rownames(otu) <- paste0("Name",seq(1,6,1))
otu
#>       Sample1 Sample2 Sample3 Sample4
#> Name1       1     3.5       0       7
#> Name2       2     3.5      15       7
#> Name3       3     3.5       0       0
#> Name4       4     3.5       4       7
#> Name5       5     3.5       2       0
#> Name6       6     3.5       0       0

tax <- data.frame(HighestRank = paste0("HighRank",c(1,2,1,1,1,1)),
                  LowestRank = paste0("LowRank",c(1,2,1,3,3,3)))
rownames(tax) <- paste0("Name",seq(1,6,1))
tax
#>       HighestRank LowestRank
#> Name1   HighRank1   LowRank1
#> Name2   HighRank2   LowRank2
#> Name3   HighRank1   LowRank1
#> Name4   HighRank1   LowRank3
#> Name5   HighRank1   LowRank3
#> Name6   HighRank1   LowRank3

foo <- phyloseq(otu_table(as.matrix(otu), taxa_are_rows = TRUE),
                tax_table(as.matrix(tax)))
foo
#> phyloseq-class experiment-level object
#> otu_table()   OTU Table:         [ 6 taxa and 4 samples ]
#> tax_table()   Taxonomy Table:    [ 6 taxa by 2 taxonomic ranks ]

# Write a function that takes the physloseq object, 
# Aggregates it according to wished rank
# And filters taxa given a character vector

fooFunction <- function(physeq, taxa, rank = "Names"){
  if(rank != "Names"){ # Condition can be tested using a string
  # Aggregate object by wished rank
  ag.physeq <- tax_glom(physeq, rank)
  ag.names <- tax_table(ag.physeq) %>% data.frame() %>% pull({{rank}})
  new.names <- paste(rownames(otu_table(ag.physeq)),ag.names,sep="_")
  
  taxa=paste0(taxa,collapse="|") # Modify character vector to a regex
  
  # Do some stuff using dplyr variable assignment and call to variable
  ag.physeq %>% 
    otu_table %>%
    as.data.frame() %>%
    rownames_to_column(var = "Names") %>%
    mutate({{rank}}:=new.names) %>%
    filter(grepl(taxa, {{rank}}))
}
}

# Expected behavior
taxa <- c("LowRank1","LowRank2")

ag.physeq <- tax_glom(foo, "LowestRank")
ag.names <- tax_table(ag.physeq) %>% data.frame() %>% pull(LowestRank)
new.names <- paste(rownames(otu_table(ag.physeq)),ag.names,sep="_")

taxa=paste0(taxa,collapse="|")

ag.physeq %>% 
  otu_table %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  rownames_to_column(var = "Names") %>%
  mutate(LowestRank=new.names) %>%
  filter(grepl(taxa, LowestRank))
#>   Names Sample1 Sample2 Sample3 Sample4     LowestRank
#> 1 Name1       4     7.0       0       7 Name1_LowRank1
#> 2 Name2       2     3.5      15       7 Name2_LowRank2
```

Option 1: passing a character string as `rank` to the function

```
fooFunction(foo, taxa=c("LowRank1","LowRank2"), rank = "LowestRank")
#> [1] Names      Sample1    Sample2    Sample3    Sample4    LowestRank
#> <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Here, the filter step does not work because the call to grepl is wrong

Option 2: `rank` is not a character string

```
fooFunction(foo, taxa=c("LowRank1","LowRank2"), rank = LowestRank)
#> Error in fooFunction(foo, taxa = c("LowRank1", "LowRank2"), rank = LowestRank): object 'LowestRank' not found
```

The conditional test does not work because `rank` does not exist.

Even if getting rid of the condition, there are others functions that require the argument as a string, *e.g.*

```
fooFunction2 <- function(physeq, taxa, rank = "Names"){
  # Aggregate object by wished rank
  ag.physeq <- tax_glom(physeq, as.character(rank))
  ag.physeq
  }

fooFunction2(foo, taxa=c("LowRank1","LowRank2"), rank = LowestRank)
#> Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)): error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function '%in%': object 'LowestRank' not found
```

Here also `rank` is not found because it does not exist.

I'd be extremely grateful for an explanation how to rightfully manage those arguments within a function!

<sup>Created on 2022-11-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just replace the filter call with a modified version that takes a character argument:

```
fooFunction <- function(physeq, taxa, rank = "Names"){
  
  if(rank != "Names"){ # Condition can be tested using a string
    # Aggregate object by wished rank
    ag.physeq <- tax_glom(physeq, rank)
    ag.names <- tax_table(ag.physeq) %>% data.frame() %>% pull({{rank}})
    new.names <- paste(rownames(otu_table(ag.physeq)),ag.names,sep="_")
    
    taxa=paste0(taxa,collapse="|") # Modify character vector to a regex
    
    # Do some stuff using dplyr variable assignment and call to variable
    ag.physeq %>% 
      otu_table %>%
      as.data.frame() %>%
      rownames_to_column(var = "Names") %>%
      mutate({{rank}}:=new.names) %>%
      filter(grepl(taxa, .[[rank]])) # use .[[ syntax to allow for characters
  }
}

fooFunction(foo, taxa=c("LowRank1","LowRank2"), rank = "LowestRank")

#>   Names Sample1 Sample2 Sample3 Sample4     LowestRank
#> 1 Name1       4     7.0       0       7 Name1_LowRank1
#> 2 Name2       2     3.5      15       7 Name2_LowRank2
```

Comment: Thank you, similarly if I use `group_by` somewhere with `rank` I need to use the `.[[rank]]` syntax. But I also use another argument which is only used in `dplyr` function and for which I use the `{{variable}}` syntax. So I end up playing with several syntaxes in one single call, which isn't optimal. Would there be a way to write the function better so as to harmonize those syntaxes?

Comment: Why is multiple syntaxes not ideal? That's why there are the special syntaxes to deal with different types of arguments, they are designed to accomplish exactly this

Comment: I just thought my function was written in a not so elegant and optimized way, but it does work now :)